# Populate data from One table to another with out matching Key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can any one tell me how to do this....

---

```
    Table 1                                 Table 2
      Cat_ID   Cat_Name                        Term_ID     Term_Name
       1       ab                                 1986       January 2013
       2       cd                                 1987       February 2013
       3       ef                                 1988       March 2013
       4       gh
```

I want the Output as :

---

```
   Table 3 
    Term_ID     Term_Name          CAT_ID      CAT_Name
    1986       January 2013           1      ab
    1986       January 2013           2      cd
    1986       January 2013           3      ef
    1986       January 2013           4      gh
    1987       February 2013          1      ab
    1987       February 2013          2      cd
    1987       February 2013          3      ef
    1987       February 2013          4      gh
    1988       March 2013             1      ab
    1988       March 2013             2      cd
    1988       March 2013             3      ef
    1988       March 2013             4      gh
```

I have to write it as a SQL query.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cartesian+product&oq=cartesian+product&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.2051j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) to get the Cartesian result that you want:

```
select t2.term_id, 
  t2.term_name, 
  t1.cat_id, 
  t1.cat_name
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05eab9/3).  Once you have the result, then you can INSERT the data into `table3`:

```
insert into table3 (term_id, term_name, cat_id, cat_name)
select t2.term_id, 
  t2.term_name, 
  t1.cat_id, 
  t1.cat_name
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
```

Comment: Hello Bluefeet, Thank you very much for the reply. I wanted to know how we can create temporary tables while writing large queries and use them in the same query itself. Does it optimize the queries performance or is there a better way to write large queries using a lot of views

Comment: @snp.it Please post a new question using the Ask question button, it will be easier to answer a question that way then through comments.